# Como evitar que se refresque la pagina al presionar Submit?

Tags: php

tengo un codigo PHP dentro de una pagina html, que al presionar un button Submit checa IP:Puerto, pero quiero que NO se actualice la pagina al dar los resultados (porque si esta activado mi tema dark, lo regresa al default)

Este es el codigo:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $host = "HOST/IP";
    $port = "PUERTO";
    $status = '<span class="badge badge-success"><i class="far fa-smile"></i></span> ó <span class="badge badge-danger"><i class="fas fa-frown"></i></i></span>';
    $response = 0;
} else {
    $host = $_POST['host'];
    $port = $_POST['port'];
    $status = '<span class="label label-danger">No válido</span>';
    $response = getStatus($host, $port);
    //validation
    if (!is_numeric($port) || $port < 0 || $port > 65535) {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0" />';
        echo '<script>alert("El puerto no es válido")</script>';
    }else{
        if ($response > 0) {
            $status = '<span class="badge badge-success"><i class="far fa-smile"></i></span>';
        } else {
            $status = '<span class="badge badge-danger"><i class="fas fa-frown"></i></span>';
        }
    }
}


function getStatus($host, $port)
{
    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $timeout = 2;
    $socket = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errorNo, $errorStr, $timeout);
    if (!$socket) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
        $time_taken = $end_time - $start_time;
        $time_taken = round($time_taken,5);
        return $time_taken * 1000;
    }
}
?>
```

Y este el boton:

```
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" >Checar</button>
```

¿Como evito que la pagina se refresque al dar los resultados? Es decir, que los de sin que tenga que actualizarse.

Comment: haz intentado usar JS o Jquery?

Comment: @Dohko19 No, soy nuevo en esto de PHP y el codigo lo encontre en Github, todo funciona, pero no se como usar JS para evitar que se refresque, podrias decirme como?

Comment: @BetaM me podrias decir como? Ya lo explique arriba, me ayudarian mucho dandome el codigo :(

Comment: @BetaM Yo lo entiendo, yo he aprendido lo poco que se viendo otros codigos y me ha funcionado bien, por eso pedia que alguien me lo convirtiera. Llevo dias intentando y por eso recurri a este foro amigo, creeme que ya lo he intentado y nada! Se que parece abusivo el pedir que me lo hagan, pero ya no se que mas hacer, por favor ayuda :(

Comment: No entiendo porqué se cambia el tema al ejecutar el formulario y supongo que pasará también con otros formularios en el sitio, solo hay que ver en qué momento pasa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rsuelto con:

```
    const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
if (currentTheme == "dark") {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
} else if (currentTheme == "light") {
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
}
```

para evitar el cambio de tema al refresh.